# Guidance on using Scoped Model Driven

Tags: struts2

My problem is I am retrieving the class but not able to set it and display it on the form while using the edit option.

The Flow is

1. CLICK on edit and retrieve the class to update
2. Now display the retrieved on the form and then update the value.

The problem is I am able to retrieve but not able to set the value in my form.

I am using model driven.

I searched on net and the solution is using scoped model driven but I am not getting any examples on how to use it.

Would be helpful if someone could guide me, I am stuck here.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: wanted Ask how to use scopemodeldriven interceptor

Comment: Right, and I'm asking what, specifically, you don't understand. Have you read the docs and looked at the example?

Answer (score 0):

Send the primary key and the operation=Edit on EditOption 
-getModel will be called as soon as the action is called again 
and in your action you can define as

```
if("Edit".equalsIgnoreCase(operation)){
   user = userServiceInterface.get(user);----(get by primary key)
System.out.println or log->("user==> "+user);
}
```

now redirect it to your jsp with the form 
Hope this helps